# Memory leak in placement new of standard library string

Tags: c++, linux, solaris

I am facing a memory leak in placement new of standard library string.

Below i have given the code where the leak is showing.

```
string string1("new string");
char _string[sizeof(string)];
new(_string) string(string1);
```

The leak is found using dbx, and it is shown as below

```
Actual leaks report    (actual leaks:            1  total size:         52 bytes)

  Total     Num of  Leaked     Allocation call stack
  Size      Blocks  Block
                    Address
==========  ====== =========== =======================================
        52       1    0x43f68  operator new < std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::__getRep < std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string < main


Possible leaks report  (possible leaks:          0  total size:          0 bytes)
```

Is this the real memory leakage or is the dbx intrepreting this as leak?

Comment: Are you calling the `std::string` destructor for `_string` anywhere?

Comment: *What are you trying to achieve?* I.e., why do you ever use placement new? What's the original problem you are trying to solve using this broken solution (I mean, placement new is broken solution, unless your code executes in environment that doesn't have real memory management)?

Comment: Note that your `_string` array is not guaranteed to be suitably aligned for `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to call the destructor for the string object you created by placement new.

`std::string` allocates the storage for the chars it stores on the heap (unless you specify a custom allocator, which might be what you're after here), and you're leaking that. (`sizeof(string)` is a constant, doesn't depend on what is stored in the string.)

Comment: Nitpick: you need to *explicitly* call the destructor of *all* objects created by placement `new`. Example: `name.~string();`.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for answers. I have tried to call destructor as _string->~string() before, it was giving compilation errors and strucked up and i was in confusion whether we should call STL::destructors in this case. Now i just tried to typecast to string and called destructor. Now it is not giving any leaks. ((string*)_string)->~string()

Comment: @user1357856: that's the right thing to do, but the _even more right_ thing to do would be not to use placement new in the case, it doesn't buy you anything (except slightly crazy syntax to call the destructor). The string "contents" is still allocated with `new`, on the heap, with the code you have there, so it doesn't do anything useful as far as I can tell.