# Memory leak after moving a std::string with placement new

Tags: c++, string, c++11, memory-leaks, move

I have a structure that contains a string and that structure is used in a vector. When the vector grows, all of the elements are moved to the new allocation. Unfortunately, this move also results in std::string leaking memory.

Here are a few minimum reproducible cases. This first example will illustrate where a memory leak occurs but sense can be made of it. The second example will cover the memory leak that has stumped me. The third will take it a step further. Last, I will show the actual use case to demonstrate what I am even doing and why I am asking this question.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
  char* allocation = new char[sizeof(std::string)];
  std::string start("start");
  std::string* move = (std::string*)allocation;
  new (move) std::string(std::move(start));
  delete[] allocation;
}
```

Unsurprisingly, this results in a memory leak. The `start` string is constructed and memory should be allocated for the data. That string is then moved into `move` and remains there for the rest of the program. Because it has been moved, the destructor for `move` will not be called and this will result in a memory leak like the one below. The reason I am creating a character array is to avoid the default constructor and destructor calls for the `move` string.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{207} normal block at 0x00000278D16848C0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  g x           > D0 D7 67 D1 78 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
```

An interesting thing to note here is that the data `<  g x           >` does not contain the string used to initialize `start`, which probably indicates that this leak is not coming from the string`s buffer.

Now we'll add one line to the previous example in an attempt to remove the memory leak.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
  char* allocation = new char[sizeof(std::string)];
  std::string start("start");
  std::string* move = (std::string*)allocation;
  new (move) std::string(std::move(start));
  start = std::move(*move); // The new line.
  delete[] allocation;
}
```

Now, instead of that string remaining in `move` until the end of the program, it is moved back into `start` and since `start's` destructor should be called, the string's allocation should be freed. However, when I run this, I still experience a similar memory leak.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{207} normal block at 0x000001AE813FECC0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  @             > 80 15 40 81 AE 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
```

I also attempted this test with a single string allocation rather than allocating a character array and I still experience a similar memory leak with the code below.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
  std::string start("start");
  std::string* move = new std::string;
  new (move) std::string(std::move(start));
  start = std::move(*move);
  delete move;
}
```

The reason I am doing all of this is because I am writing my own version of vector. When my vector grows, and the type contained within the vector contains a string, the memory leak that I've highlighted above occurs. This is what my grow function looks like. `Util::Move` is my own version of `std::move`. I am doing a lot of this for curiosity, learning, and entertainment purposes.

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::Grow(int newCapacity)
{
  LogAbortIf(
    newCapacity <= mCapacity,
    "The new capacity must be greater than the current capacity.");

  T* oldData = mData;
  mData = CreateAllocation(newCapacity);
  for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
  {
    new (mData + i) T(Util::Move(oldData[i]));
  }
  mCapacity = newCapacity;
  DeleteAllocation(oldData);
}

// Using this struct in the vector would cause a leak.
struct Example
{
  std::string mString;
};
```

Why would this memory leak happen? Is there something about std::string that I am missing here or is my use of placement new somehow the culprit?

Additional Notes:
[Memory leak in placement new of standard library string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346447/memory-leak-in-placement-new-of-standard-library-string) - This question only covers my first example. It does not explain or cover the last two.

Comment: "*it is moved back into `start` and this means that `start`'s destructor should be called*" - why would it mean that?

Comment: Your third example is completely different: you are manually overwriting an allocated `std::string` object without manually running its destructor. So of course that destructor is never run. The first and second examples are both strictly speaking UB in current C++ (though this is considered a defect in the standard). I’m actually surprised at the memory leak anyway: due to SBO, the string instance shouldn’t free any dynamic memory in its destructor.

Comment: @Fureeish I'll edit that. Just some poor wording on my part. The destructor should be called regardless.

Comment: @Fureeish `start`’s destructor will *always* be run. I think what OP means is that, since a valid object was moved back into the memory occupied by `start`, the destructor will be run on that object. Of course the moved-from’s object destructor *also* needs to be run (but isn’t, because it’s just a bunch of bytes, not really a string).

Comment: All your examples are missing calls to a destructor. All of them shows a memory leak. Might not be a coincidence?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't understand your note about the last example. Shouldn't the destructor for both `move` and `start` be called? `move` 's is called on `delete move` and `start`'s is called when it goes out of scope. However, you do make a good point that I am overwriting an allocated string with a move constructor when I don't necessarily know if the default constructor for string creates an allocation.

Comment: @Underdisc You’re confusing *objects* and *variables*. In the third example, the *variable* `move` refers to two different `std::string` *objects* over its lifetime. You are overwriting the first object without ever deleting it (and you’re also not deleting the second object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from an object does not imply that the destructor does not need to be called. *Any* constructed object needs to be destructed:

```
{
    std::string s;
    std::move(s);
} // s’ destructor is run here!
```

The same is true for the object in your code that you constructed explicitly via placement-new (at the address `move`). The issue is that, since it resides inside dynamically allocated memory, its destructor isn’t run automatically, and when you delete the *`char` array* that’s underlying the memory, you tell C++ not to consider the bytes of that storage location to be occupied by a `std::string` object.

In brief, the solution is to run the `std::string` destructor manually before freeing the storage:

```
move->std::string::~string();
delete[] allocation;
```

Do this for every placement-new.

Comment: @Underdisc Thanks, I’ve edited the answer since I agree with you that your phrasing is better, and expresses exactly what I intended to say.

Comment: The edit queue is full, so I am going to put this here. `Moving from an object does not prevent its destructor being run (nor needing to be run)`. I would change this to. `Moving from an object does not imply that the destructor does not need to be called. Any constructed object needs to be destructed`. This highlights the exact mistake I was making in all of my examples. *I deleted this comment after the edit was, so I wanted to put it back since there is a reply. This came before the reply above*. I'm going to also make this the accepted answer since it gets right to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Because it has been moved, the destructor for move will not be called

No, this is wrong. The destructor for the object known as `*move` will not be called because `move` is a raw pointer.

If it were to be called automatically, it would have happened *after* you deleted the underlying allocation, so it would cause UB anyway. This code is completely nonsensical.

> The reason I am creating a character array is to avoid the constructor and destructor calls for the move string

You explicitly called placement new, so this is also nonsense. How does deliberately invoking the move constructor avoid the constructor?

The only thing you *have* avoided is the destructor, and this is a bug rather than an optimization.

> ... this means that `start`'s destructor should be called and the string's allocation should be freed ...

`start`'s destructor *will* be called whatever you do, because it's an automatic local. It was called in the first example too. However, you're assuming that moving *from* `*move` means its ok not to call its destructor. This isn't true, it's still a bug (and would still be a bug even if it didn't leak).

Your final test dynamically allocates (and default constructs) a string, and then placement-new's another string over its storage, without first destroying it. This is *also* nonsense.

---

You problems, in order, are:

1. You haven't shown the real code that leaks, so we can't really explain that leak. All your examples are simply wrong, so we can only speculate that your real code may be wrong in the same way.
2. You're trying to optimize something that may not benefit from it. Many library implementations will use the short string optimization for a five character string - find out whether yours is one of them.

   For that matter, don't forget to profile your code before you start optimizing it.
3. You're trying to optimize something that may not require it, using a technique you don't understand.

   You need to understand object lifetime rules, and when constructors and destructors are invoked, *before* you start trying to use placement new. Manually controlling object and storage lifetimes is fairly advanced, and you can't do it properly unless you understand the default behaviour in the first place.

   The usual learning experiment is to write a toy class with all constructors, assignment operators and the destructor implemented, and all printing something. Then you can easily *see* what happens by replacing `std::string` with your class in those examples.

Comment: `How does deliberately invoking the move constructor avoid the constructor?`
Bad wording on my part. It was specifically to avoid the default constructor with the intent of only using the move constructor.

Comment: `However, you're assuming that moving from *move means its ok not to call its destructor. This isn't true, it's still a bug (and would still be a bug even if it didn't leak).` This gets down to my exact problem. I have been making the assumption that moving from an object implies that the object moved from no longer owns any allocations. This incorrect assumption about move semantics definitely contributed to the high degree of nonsense.

Comment: I don't think that's a totally unreasonable expectation (it might not be correct, but it's understandable). However, even if that were true, it wouldn't be OK to skip the destructor. Even if there were no memory leak - or potentially any other visible effect - it would still be _wrong_, and prone to suddenly breaking on a different or newer compiler, or with different flags, or just because.

Comment: Very true. I have been writing move constructors for a lot of my own structures, and all of the structures are able to be moved from in a way that allows avoiding calls to the destructor.  I suppose this started to make me think that doing such a thing is ok.

Comment: `If it were to be called automatically, it would have happened after you deleted the underlying allocation, so it would cause UB anyway.` What do you mean by `UB` here btw?

Comment: Calling the destructor on the object formerly known as `*move` _after_ the raw storage pointed to by `move` has been released is a problem. You gave that memory back, and can't do anything with it. Dereferencing the pointer, or really using that address at all after deallocation, is Undefined Behaviour. The OS could have unmapped it for all you know, and reused the address for that I/O mapped nuclear weapon you keep forgetting to disconnect.